# How to send files using discord.net?

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I am creating a discord bot, and I want one of the commands "woah" to post an image (wymi.gif). I have tried the following code, but it does not output anything when I type +woah (+ is the prefix). I have tried other commands that do not output images and they do work, so the bot is functional in that sense.

```
else if (command.Equals("woah"))
{
    message.Channel.SendFileAsync("@C:/Users/pwcub/source/repos/discord bot/discord bot/bin/Debug/net6.0/wymi.gif");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `await` in front of that call ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have fixed the issue by placing the file in another directory lol. All is functional now. How do I close a question?

Comment: @Fprime - You don't need to close the question if you can make it a relevant to the answer you've found. Ideally you should do that. So, I can't see anything in the question that could lead someone to offer the "place file in another directory" solution. Can you put the salient information in the question? And then, if you cant, post your answer as an answer. Then this question become useful to future readers. Alternatively, you can delete the question. :-)